# How to make DC motor rotate a specific number of turns?

Tags: arduino-uno, code-review

Can someone please give the code which can be used to rotate the dc motor a specific number of rotations like 2 rotations or 5 rotations. I'm using arduino uno board.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a *gimme da code* site.

Comment: Hi @Rohit and welcome to the Arduino SE community. Unfortunately your question doesn't meet our quality standards. Please edit and improve it. [How to ask](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

You can't. You either have to attach a sensor to the motor shaft to measure the numbers of rotations or use a stepper motor.

Answer (score 0):

No! That is not how motors work.

If you need precision control you need to use a stepper motor or servo.

You could implement some solution with a geared motor and position sensor, but this really only works (imprecisely) with a slow rotation speed.

Answer (score -1):

> Can someone please give the code which can be used to rotate the dc motor a specific number of rotations like 2 rotations or 5 rotations.

fairly simple:

```
rotation_count = 0; //initialize rotation counter
motor_on();  //turn on the motor
while (rotation_count < DESIRED_COUNT) {
  rotation_count = count_rotation(); //update rotation count
};
motor_off(); //turn off the motor
```